# how to extract the result of an AngularFirestoreCollection into an array

Tags: angular, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

The app I am trying to develop allows the choice of language using a Material2 Select input field. The available languages are held in a Firestore collection of documents. I use an AngularFirestoreCollection to retrieve them but cannot find out how to extract the language names from the result and put them into an array.

I have googled for examples and tutorials, read and re-read pages of documentation and found many examples using ‘*ngFor’ but I cannot find any using ‘map’ which I suspect is what I need to use.

Thank you in advance.

```
  languageid: string;
  languageName: string;
  languageCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> = this.afs.collection('Countries/AU/cLanguage');
  languagecollection = this.languageCollection.valueChanges();
  languages: string[];
```

I want to map "languagecollection = this.languageCollection.valueChanges();" to an array.

Comment: post the code you tried.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply but I am on the other side of the world.                         languageid: string;
  languageName: string;
  languageCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> = this.afs.collection('Countries/AU/cLanguage');
  languagecollection = this.languageCollection.valueChanges();
  languages: string[];      // I need     => map (mappedData)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like: (untested. comment if it's wrong)

```
let languages: string[];
let collection = this.afs.collection('Countries/AU/cLanguage').valueChanges();

//if you want to Firebase's .once(), use take(1)
let storeTask = collection.subscribe((langs) => {
    languages = langs;

    //Or 
    /*Object.keys(langs).map(function(key, index) {
       languages.push(langs[key].name)
    });*/
});
```

Comment: I get an error on take(1): "[ts] Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}[]>'.

Comment: I think `take(1)` works in the newrst version. But you can remove it and take advantage of realtime atualization.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code did what I needed

```
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    let name = doc.data()['languageName']; 
    lang.push(name);
  });
});
```